# Why is NDSolve's StartingStepSize with ExplicitEuler not working? How do I set the step size?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Why do I get a **smooth** curve (that is obviously wrong) when I run this?

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, {x[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}]],
 {t, 0, 1},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Shouldn't I just get back a straight line connecting (0, 1) to (1, 0)?!

How do I make Mathematica just do a plain classic Forward Euler?! I don't want fancy smoothing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set [`MaxStepFraction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxStepFraction.html), too, say, to `1`.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, {x[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"},
   MaxStepFraction -> 1]],
 {t, 0, 1},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's not a straight line because the value of the derivatives are stored & used in the `InterpolatingFunction` solution.  However, we can see there are only two points.

```
sol /. t -> "Grid"
(*  {{{0.}, {1.}}}  *)
```

Comment: +1 Ahhh! Is there any way to make it draw without smoothing then? It's so misleading the way it draws it...

Comment: @Mehrdad Oops, made a mistake editing the comment. Try `sol1 = Interpolation[Table[{t, sol}, {t, Flatten[sol /. t -> "Grid"]}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]`.

Comment: Awesome, got it! It ended up being `sol = Evaluate[
   NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 1, MaxStepFraction -> 1, 
    Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}]];
sol = Interpolation[Table[{t, sol}, {t, Flatten[sol /. t -> "Grid"]}],
     InterpolationOrder -> 1][t];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: PS, this might be more painful but for future reference it might be nice to add how to do it if we're solving for multiple values (e.g. `{x[t], x'[t]}`).

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm not sure what you mean, actually.  But, one can plot a linear interpolation with `ListLinePlot[sol = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}, StartingStepSize -> 1, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, MaxStepFraction -> 1]]`, even though `sol` is still order 3.  `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot` show only the steps, or interpolated points, in an `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: Oh, I meant what if I want to plot something like `NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, {x[t], x'[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]`? Then `Flatten` will do the wrong thing.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The simplest way to go about this would be to set the `InterpolationOrder -> 1` option in `NDSolve`. Apparetnly this is ignored and `InterpolatingFunction` is of order 3...

Comment: @mmal Yes, I tried that.  `InterpolationOrder -> 0` generates an error; everything else seems ignored.  `InterpolationOrder -> All` is the only setting shown in the docs, and it seems to do something rather interesting (too long for a comment).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest (as an alternative) the following

```
pointsAndValues[x_InterpolatingFunction] :=
  Transpose[{First[x["Coordinates"]], x["ValuesOnGrid"]}];

ListPlot[
  pointsAndValues@
    First@NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, {x}, {t, 0, 3}, 
      StartingStepSize -> 1, 
      Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, 
      MaxStepFraction -> 1], Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

And to check the convergence use e.g.

```
ListPlot[pointsAndValues@
  First@NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, {x}, {t, 0, 2}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 1/#, 
    Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, 
    MaxStepFraction -> 1] & /@ {1, 2, 4, 16}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more polished version of the currently accepted answer:

```
Reinterpolate[interpolation_, args___] := 
  Interpolation[
   Transpose[
    Append[Transpose[interpolation["Grid"]], 
     interpolation["ValuesOnGrid"]]], args];
ReinterpolateAll[expr_, args___] := 
  expr /. {InterpolatingFunction[params___] :> 
     Reinterpolate[InterpolatingFunction[params], args]};
sol = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 10}, x[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/3, MaxStepFraction -> 1, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];
Plot[Evaluate[ReinterpolateAll[sol, InterpolationOrder -> 1]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```