# Force ExplicitEuler Method of NDSolve to produce simple "connect the dot" plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, dynamic

The code plots the solution to an ordinary differential equation (ODE) on its corresponding vector field by one of two methods: (1) click on an initial point of the vector field or (2) keyboard entry of an initial point. In particular, I generate an explicit Euler approximate solution for a given step size. For simplicity I have fixed the step size to be 1/2. An ODE of the form $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=f\left( t,x\right)$ may be inputted by the user; a default ODE is provided with $f\left( t,x\right) =x^{2}-t$.

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{g = {}, dx, sol, t0, x0, diffEq},
diffEq = x^2 - t;
dx[de_] := diffEq;
sol[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] := 
y[t] /. First@NDSolve[{y'[t] == dx /. {x -> y[t]}, y[t0] == x0, 
   WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 2.0, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, -2, 2},
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/2, MaxStepFraction -> 1,
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &,"WarningMessage" -> False}];  

Column[{
Row[{Style["Enter f(t,x) "]}],
Row[{Style["dx/dt = "], InputField[Dynamic@diffEq]}],
Row[{Style["Keyboard Entry "], Spacer[20],
Control[{{t0, Null, "t0 ="}, ImageSize -> 30}], Spacer[20],
Control[{{x0, Null, "t0 ="}, ImageSize -> 30}], Spacer[20],
Button["Add solution",If[NumericQ@t0 && NumericQ@x0,
AppendTo[g, sol[dx[diffEq], {t0, x0}]]
]]
}],
Dynamic@ClickPane[
Show[
Plot[g, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
Axes -> None, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium], 
VectorPlot[{1, dx[diffEq]}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}]],
(AppendTo[g, sol[dx[diffEq], #]]) &],
Button["Delete all solutions", g = {}]
}]]
```

The result of plotting either method yields a smooth plot from interpolated points. What I want is a solution that looks like the image below where I have chosen the initial point to be (t0,x0)=(0,0) and step size 0.5. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

I have examined Michael E2's [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107378/why-is-ndsolves-startingstepsize-with-expliciteuler-not-working-how-do-i-set-t) and Mark McClure's [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/ndsolve-with-euler-method), but neither works for me. I suspect my issue is with with the manner in which I "Show" my plots. I need to retain the ClickPane construction as this code is but a snippet of a much larger code.

I appreciate any help you may offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListLinePlot[{InterpolationFunction[..],..}]` will plot the steps stored in the solutions returned by `NDSolve`.  I had to change the OP's code slightly to get the pure `InterpolationFunction` represented by `y`, instead of `y[t]`.

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{g = {}, dx, sol, t0, x0, diffEq}, 
  diffEq = x^2 - t;
  dx[de_] := diffEq;
  sol[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] :=    (* changed to y from y[t], to get InterpolationFunction *)
   y /. First@
     NDSolve[{y'[t] == dx /. {x -> y[t]}, y[t0] == x0, 
       WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 2.0, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, -2, 2}, 
      Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, 
      StartingStepSize -> 1/2, MaxStepFraction -> 1, 
      "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
        "WarningMessage" -> False}];
  Column[{Row[{Style["Enter f(t,x) "]}], 
    Row[{Style["dx/dt = "], InputField[Dynamic@diffEq]}], 
    Row[{Style["Keyboard Entry "], Spacer[20], 
      Control[{{t0, Null, "t0 ="}, ImageSize -> 30}], Spacer[20], 
      Control[{{x0, Null, "t0 ="}, ImageSize -> 30}], Spacer[20], 
      Button["Add solution", 
       If[NumericQ@t0 && NumericQ@x0, 
        AppendTo[g, sol[dx[diffEq], {t0, x0}]]]]}], 
    Dynamic@ClickPane[Show[
       ListLinePlot[g, Mesh -> All],              (* remove Mesh->All to remove dots *)
       VectorPlot[{1, dx[diffEq]}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
        VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}],
       AspectRatio -> Automatic,
       PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
       ImageSize -> Medium,
       Options[ListPlot]],        (* keeps plot from jumping when first sol is added *)
      (AppendTo[g, sol[dx[diffEq], #]]) &], 
    Button["Delete all solutions", g = {}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the dots to match the color of the lines, you replace `ListLinePlot[g]` with the following:

```
Table[
 ListLinePlot[g[[i]], Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][i]],
 {i, Length@g}]
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Thanks so much.
I replaced StartingStepSize -> 1/2 with StartingStepSize -> h and added h_ to sol in order to input step size as well.

Comment: @Stephen You're welcome.  It's a nice demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

You need `StepMonitor[ ]` to generate the points. `{Sow[ ],Reap[ ]}`is a good alternative to collect them

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{g = {{0, {{10, 10}}}}, dx, sol, t0, x0, diffEq}, 
  Clear[x, y];
  diffEq = x^2 - t;
  dx[de_] := diffEq;
  sol[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] := 
   sol[dx, {t0, x0}] = 
    Reap[y[t] /. 
      First@NDSolve[{y'[t] == dx /. {x -> y[t]}, y[t0] == x0, 
         WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 2.0, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, -2, 2},
        Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"},
        StartingStepSize -> 1/2, MaxStepFraction -> 1, 
        "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False},
        StepMonitor :> (Sow[{t, y[t]}])]];
  Column[{Row[{Style["Enter f(t,x) "]}], 
    Row[{Style["dx/dt = "], InputField[Dynamic@diffEq]}], 
    Row[{Style["Keyboard Entry "], Spacer[20], 
      Control[{{t0, Null, "t0 ="}, ImageSize -> 30}], Spacer[20], 
      Control[{{x0, Null, "t0 ="}, ImageSize -> 30}], Spacer[20], 
      Button["Add solution", 
       If[NumericQ@t0 && NumericQ@x0, 
        AppendTo[g, sol[dx[diffEq], {t0, x0}]]]]}], Dynamic@ClickPane[
      Show[
       ListLinePlot[Sort /@ First /@ Last /@ g, 
        PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
        ImageSize -> Medium], 
       VectorPlot[{1, dx[diffEq]}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
        VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}]], (AppendTo[g, 
         r = sol[dx[diffEq], #]]) &],
    Button["Delete all solutions",
     g = {{0, {{10, 10}}}}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]